# Python regex get tag content not tag name

Tags: python, html, regex, tags

I have following problem: I have some HTML code and I need to get tag content. I don't want to use millions of substring or something like that. I want to use regex but I am having problem with filtering tags with classes, ids,... or without anything. Here's my regex:

```
match = re.search('(?<=<span(.+)?>)(.*)(?=</span>)', '<span class="red">color</span>')
```

Python throws following error

```
sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

I want to get content from

```
<span class="red">color</span>
```

and from

```
<span>color</span>
```

Thanks everyone from help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: *Why* do people insist on using regex to parse HTML?

Comment: must you use regex ? why not a html parser like beautifull soup

Comment: use `beautifulsoup` instead of writing regex

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: Use `findall`, skip the look-behind and get the capture group.

```
<span(.+)?>(.*?)</span>
```

But this **will** fail in many cases. E.g. nested tags, a string containing the text *</span>*, and so on...